# What Dominion cards have artwork featuring different versions of the same object?

Tags: dominion

In the Dark Ages expansion of Dominion there are several cards that feature artwork with run-down versions of the artwork on previously released cards. Examples are "Pillage" - featuring "Village," "Ruined Library" - featuring "Library", and "Ruined Village" - featuring the promo card, "Walled Village."

What other cards in the Dominion world feature artwork with various versions of the same object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The vast majority of the cards feature unique artwork, which is great. However, there are some cards that indeed include other cards' artwork, like:

1. **Scrying Pool** (from Dominion: Alchemy) depicts the artwork from *Village*. Just turn the card upside-down to see the reflection in the pool.
2. **Minion** (from Dominion: Intrigue) displays a  portrait of a Minion. Self-reference.
3. If you put **Island**, **Pirate Ship** and **Native Village** (from Dominion: Seaside) next to each other, in this order, you shall notice that their artworks make up a greater panorama.
4. On the same token, most **Split Piles** from Dominion: Empires and the Sauna/Avanto promos feature continuous artwork.
5. Likewise, the two traveler lines, **Page** and **Peasant** (from Dominion: Adventures), illustrate the same person in evolving stages of their lives. (added by *@Gendolkari*)
6. **Candlestick Maker** (from Dominion: Guilds) is crafting the candle depicted on *Masterpiece*, from the same expansion.
7. As mentioned, **Pillage** (from Dominion: Dark Ages) depicts a *Village* under attack.
8. As mentioned, most **Ruins** depict destroyed versions of other cards: Ruined Village/Mine/Library/Market depict *Village*/*Mine*/*Library*/*Grand Market* respectively.
9. **Overgrown Estate** (Shelter from Dominion: Dark Ages) lives up to its name by depicting an abandoned version of the *Estate* artwork, as illustrated in the second version of the base game and in Dominion: Base Cards. (added by *@Ned Strong*)

Cards that pay homage to other games:

1. **City** (from Dominion: Prosperity) displays the box art from the game *Carcassonne: The City*.
2. **Governor** (Promo) displays the Governor role art from *Puerto Rico: Limited Anniversary Edition*. Its card symbol, a ship, is the same ship from the box art.
3. The **Walled Village** (Promo) card's symbol is a meeple from *Carcassonne*. The card itself supposedly depicts Carcassonne, as well.

Comment: Great answer! For completeness, each Traveller line from Adventures includes 5 cards with all pictures of the same person at different life stages.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback. I will add these too with proper credit.

Comment: The Madman is an upgraded version of the Hermit, and the Mercenary is an upgraded version of the Urchin (the small boy on the Urchin card). Another possibility is that if you look near the back of Bandit Camp from Dominion: Dark Ages, you'll see a dark hooded bandit wielding a knife with a sword resting nearby. The new Bandit card from Dominion: Second Edition features a very similar bandit, wielding a knife and a sword.

Comment: The Butcher, the Baker, and the Candlestick Maker from Guilds make a clever set. Not the same artwork on separate cards, but very intentionally connected via nursery rhyme.